# Point cloud view point changed after loading and rewriting the point cloud

Tags: c++, point-cloud-library, point-clouds

I just simply load and rewrite a ply file using [pcl](http://www.pointclouds.org).

```
void main (int argc, char** argv)
{
    // Fetch point cloud filename in arguments | Works with PCD and PLY files
    std::vector<int> filenames;
    bool file_is_pcd = false;

    filenames = pcl::console::parse_file_extension_argument (argc, argv, ".ply");

    if (filenames.size () != 1)  {
        filenames = pcl::console::parse_file_extension_argument (argc, argv, ".pcd");

        if (filenames.size () != 1) {
            showHelp (argv[0]);
            return -1;
        } else {
            file_is_pcd = true;
        }
    }

    // Load file | Works with PCD and PLY files
    pcl::PointCloud<pcl::PointXYZRGB>::Ptr source_cloud (new pcl::PointCloud<pcl::PointXYZRGB> ());

    if (file_is_pcd) {
        if (pcl::io::loadPCDFile (argv[filenames[0]], *source_cloud) < 0)  {
            std::cout << "Error loading point cloud " << argv[filenames[0]] << std::endl << std::endl;
            showHelp (argv[0]);
            return -1;
        }
    } else {
        if (pcl::io::loadPLYFile (argv[filenames[0]], *source_cloud) < 0)  {
            std::cout << "Error loading point cloud " << argv[filenames[0]] << std::endl << std::endl;
            showHelp (argv[0]);
            return -1;
        }
    }

    pcl::io::savePLYFileBinary("gt_2.ply", *source_cloud);
}
```

But when I checked the ply file after rewriting ,the initial 
view point of point cloud has been changed. I mean the point cloud transformed. I used plyv tool in [cvkit](https://github.com/roboception/cvkit) to view ply files.

Comment: pcl casts all coordinates to floats. If your ply has large coordinates in text or double binary format then all of them may suffer from significant loss of precision after casting to floats.

Comment: I don't think this is the reason , as I converted the ply file to xyz file and check the vertices coordinates.